# Why does MobileSubstrate use such a long function name when hooking C++ functions?

Tags: c++, c, hook

From [the example of hooking C++ methods with MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate#Example_code) I found this:

```
void (*X_ZN20WebFrameLoaderClient23dispatchWillSendRequestEPN7WebCore14DocumentLoaderEmRNS0_15ResourceRequestERKNS0_16ResourceResponseE) (void* something, void* loader, unsigned long identifier,  void* request, const void** response);
```

Why do we need this x_zn20...23....7...14 etc. between the names? What does this mean? I don't think that this is the real name.

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm thinking that has to do with name mangling.  The function names you declare in C++ get "mangled" into nasty symbol names like that as the compiler's way of dealing with things like overloaded functions and multiple classes with functions by the same name.

Comment: What does this have to do with C or Objective-C?

Comment: The code shown here is in C, @Nicol. It's C code for hooking a C++ function. MobileSubstrate provides examples in C and Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ mangles names of symbols emitted to the binary, to distinguish `void foo(int)` and `void foo(double)`. Also, on many platforms, it needs to encode `X::Y` somehow to make it an alphanumeric string. This adds the extra characters and is platform dependent.

Comment: Compiler specific. Lots of compilers on the same platform may have different name mangling schemes. Hence objects from different compilers rarely work together.

Comment: @LokiAstari: it's more the other way around: objects don't work together unless they adhere to a common ABI, and name mangling prevents linking of incompatible objec files 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

The notation you see is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

It's a way of encoding method signatures (in the binary) so that they are unique across the binary, even if two methods have the same name and they belong to classes of the same name, but differ only by the scope (namespace) or parameters

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some platform specific hack to bind to a symbol in a compiled object.

You should look for the header file which contains that function name and call it properly.

This is bad because as compiler evolve and the code base changes specifics of the symbol name will change.

Comment: When you're hooking a private function, you rarely have access to the header where the function is declared. And since you're hooking already-compiled code, it's best to use the name as it appears in the compiled module. Otherwise, you need re-implement the same name-mangling routine used by the compiler of the other module.